# Анимированая перестановка блоков

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация

Сделал перестановку двух блоков по клику с `flexbox` ниже.

Есть ли какой-то способ это анимировать? Может быть даже с функциями плавности (easing).

```js
$('#swap').click(function() {
 $('.swap0').toggleClass('swap1');
});
```

```css
.bk1 {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.bk2 {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.swap0 {
 display: flex;
 transition: 2s;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.swap1 {
 flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap swap0">
 <div class="bk1">

 </div>
 <div class="bk2">

 </div>
</div>

<a id="swap">SWAP THIS</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

Есть способ без флекса:

```js
$('#swap').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 $('.swap0').toggleClass('swap1');
});
```

```css
.bk1 {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.bk2 {
    background: #0f0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.swap0 {
 height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}


.swap1 .bk1 {
 top: 100px;
}
.swap1 .bk2 {
 top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap swap0">
 <div class="bk1">

 </div>
 <div class="bk2">

 </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="swap">SWAP THIS</a>
```

Comment: Думаете оптимально будет узнавать высоту блоков(ибо она неизвестна изначально) для position?

Answer (score 2):

вариант анимированной смены для flex, блоки *желательно* одинаковой высоты

```js
$('#swap').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  $('.swap0').toggleClass('swap1');
});
```

```css
.bk1 {
  background: #f00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-duration: 1.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: slideOut;
}
.bk2 {
  background: #0f0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  animation-duration: 1.25s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-name: slideIn;
}
.swap0 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
@keyframes slideIn {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
@keyframes slideOut {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
.swap1 .bk1 {
  animation-name: slideIn;
  order: 2;
}
.swap1 .bk2 {
  animation-name: slideOut;
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap swap0">
  <div class="bk1">

  </div>
  <div class="bk2">

  </div>
</div>

<a id="swap">SWAP THIS</a>
```

Comment: Та в этом и проблема что блоки могут быть разной высоты. Нужно видимо брать размеры блоков и отступы блока от начала страницы, а так спасибо за вариант, для блоков одинаковых размеров он очень полезный.